# Retrieving Database Schema Linq to SQL VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, mapping, schema

I want to retrieve each column name and data type then check if the columns is foreign key then query they key table of that relation !!! could be done  ?? I googled for 3 days I know that I have to use Mappping model OR Reflection or both ,,,, but i cant do it .

I will simplify what i need assuming : 
TABLE1 hase foreign key( COL3) refer to the primary key (COL1) in TABLE0 :

1. iterate TABLE1  Columns check EACH columns if it is a foreign key ( also get its data type)
2. Get the relation to determine the associated table(TABLE0)
3. retrieve    the primary key tables (TABLE0)

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Do you want to JOIN the data? Or simply knowing what the related table is? (To get that data for example, to display a dropdown or whatever.) Try editing your question without the many exclamation and question marks. It doesn't sound nice and sounds very yelling and desperate.

Comment: Yes I need to know what related table is . then i want to retrieve data of related table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it 
I make a function that return the type of each foreign key and the related table class type

```
Private Function GetForeignKeyTables(ByVal myTableType As Type) As List(Of myForeignKeys)

    Dim myDx = New Tester.DataClasses1DataContext
    Dim mymodel As New AttributeMappingSource

    Dim myAsociations = mymodel.GetModel(GetType(DataClasses1DataContext)).GetTable(myTableType).RowType.Associations

    Dim asc = From m In myAsociations Where m.IsForeignKey
               Select New myForeignKeys With {.KeyDataType = m.ThisKey.First.DbType, .RelatedTableType = m.OtherType}

    Return asc.ToList

End Function

Private Class myForeignKeys
    Property KeyDataType As String
    Property RelatedTableType As MetaType

End Class
```

But I still need to retrieve the data from those related table .

I mean how to create an instance of the class from its MetaType variable?

Comment: [SOLVED] I can get a table by using datacontext gettable method.                                                                          Dim table = myDx.GetTable(<MetaType>.GetType)